# GNU Make 3.82 on Ubuntu 18.04 segfault in glob call

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-make

My first ever SO Question!

I am trying to get GNU Make 3.82 installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 distro. But I am running into an issue.

I've tried the work around (modifying line 55 of glob/glob.c) mentioned [here](http://gnu-make.2324884.n4.nabble.com/undefined-reference-to-alloca-td18308.html), but to no avail. The console output below does not reflect this attempt though.

This is what happens when I try to run make in my Ubuntu 18.04 environment, after making the previously mentioned changes:

```
sgowen@stephen-Parallels-Ubuntu:~$ gdb make
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from make...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/make 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555579d381 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055555579d381 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7acba8b in glob_lstat (pglob=0x7fffffffc530, 
    fullname=0x7fffffffbc10 "./.out", flags=516) at ../posix/glob.c:204
#2  glob_in_dir (pattern=pattern@entry=0x55555579f580 ".out", 
    directory=directory@entry=0x7ffff7b997d8 <dot> ".", flags=flags@entry=516, 
    errfunc=errfunc@entry=0x0, pglob=pglob@entry=0x7fffffffc530, 
    alloca_used=<optimized out>, alloca_used@entry=0) at ../posix/glob.c:1299
#3  0x00007ffff7acc589 in __glob (pattern=pattern@entry=0x55555579f580 ".out", 
    flags=flags@entry=516, errfunc=errfunc@entry=0x0, 
    pglob=pglob@entry=0x7fffffffc530) at ../posix/glob.c:1096
#4  0x000055555556d246 in parse_file_seq (
    stringp=stringp@entry=0x7fffffffc5c0, size=size@entry=40, 
    stopchar=stopchar@entry=0, prefix=prefix@entry=0x0, flags=flags@entry=0)
    at read.c:3115
#5  0x000055555555ceda in set_default_suffixes () at default.c:545
#6  0x0000555555559eb2 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, 
    envp=<optimized out>) at main.c:1600
(gdb)
```

Comment: I tried making that change on line 55 like suggested in the thread that you referenced and it resolved the issue for me. What was the problem for you after you made that change?

Comment: Invoking make just results in a Segmentation Fault, I'll see if I can dig up more details.

Comment: A segmentation fault is quite a different type of nut to crack than a build problem. It would be good if you could add some details around that indeed, ideally something reproducible...

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek post updated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need such an old version of GNU Make?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Where I work, we use a custom fork of Android-17, that requires Make 3.82 to fully compile. Also, I should note that, I've gotten past all these issues by simply using Ubuntu 16.04. I'm sure there are some fancy ways I could make Ubuntu 18.04 work as well, but I'm a LOT less interested in figuring that out now.

Comment: @sgowen Why not compile the latest GNU Make? It is backward compatible and builds with newer compilers.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I forgot the reason... It's been so long, but I remember distinctly making the decision to use Make 3.82. At this point, I am curious if version 3.82 really is a requirement. I'll spin up another VM and try to use the latest Make and see what happens

Comment: Okay, so I haven't gotten around to testing using the latest Make, but I did come across the Android AOSP Build Requirements: https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements so this is probably where I came up with using the 3.82 version

Answer (score 1):

Purely for reference purposes, as I happened across the segfault issue myself (though with Make 4.2.1), the actual issue is due to Make making assumptions about glibc which no longer held true for newer versions.

In addition to making the alloca related changes, you need to pull in upstream commit hash [`193f1e81edd6b1b56b0eb0ff8aa4b41c7b4257b4`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/?id=193f1e81edd6b1b56b0eb0ff8aa4b41c7b4257b4)

Further details:

https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/XCYUF5BQLICUAAI3OM7EORCNOKEYP2MF/